# Asp.Net Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, encoding

I am using Querystring to pass values from one page to other. I am tring to implement encoding and decoding using the Server.UrlDecode and urlEncode.

Query string returns a null value, but I can check the values are been sent in URL.

The two pages are:

QueryString.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = "1";
    string name = "aaaa";

    string url = string.Format("QueryStringValuesTransfer.aspx?{0}&{1}", Server.UrlEncode(id), Server.UrlEncode(name));


    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

;;

In  another page :

QueryStringValuesTransfer.aspx:

```
 public partial class QueryStringValuesTransfer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id1 = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        string name1 = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["name"]);
        Response.Write(id1 + name1);

    }
```

}

---

I am get null values in the id1 and name1.

Any help please..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line:

```
string url = string.Format("QueryStringValuesTransfer.aspx?id={0}&name={1}", Server.UrlEncode(id), Server.UrlEncode(name));
```

Answer (score 3):

Right now you are only setting the values in the querystring, you need to assign them names so you can grab them again:

```
string url = string.Format("QueryStringValuesTransfer.aspx?id={0}&name={1}", Server.UrlEncode(id), Server.UrlEncode(name));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your query string should be something like

```
MyPage.aspx?id=xxx&name=yyy
```

You are not passing the values, only the names...

Answer (score 1):

```
string url = string.Format("QueryStringValuesTransfer.aspx?{0}&{1}", Server.UrlEncode(id), Server.UrlEncode(name));
```

Should be:

```
string url = string.Format("QueryStringValuesTransfer.aspx?id={0}&name={1}", Server.UrlEncode(id), Server.UrlEncode(name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying a name for the values. You need:

```
string url = string.Format("QueryStringValuesTransfer.aspx?id={0}&name={1}", Server.UrlEncode(id), Server.UrlEncode(name));
```

Answer (score 1):

When constructing the URL in the first page you should do this:

```
string url = string.Format("QueryStringValuesTransfer.aspx?id={0}&name={1}", Server.UrlEncode(id), Server.UrlEncode(name));
```

The query string consists of key-value pairs, you should provide the keys.